# Where is my connection string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have created a project call Repository.EF to handle Data access in a n-tire solution.  I have added EF to the Repository.EF project where I have all my POCO's . Then I created a DbContext class in that project like this.

```
namespace LearningSpike.Repositories.EF
{
class GlassContractDbContext:DbContext
    {
    public GlassContractDbContext() : base("GlassContractContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<MetalStock> MetalStock { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MetalStockConfiguration());
    } 
}
```

Then went to package manager console and did

```
Enable-Migrations
```

Then set the

```
 AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
```

Then

```
Update-Database
```

Everything is working fine. But the problem is, I don't know where the connection string is. It seems like there is no connectionString in that particular project. I know if I had an MVC4/5 template, there will be a connectionString in the web.config. How can I find the connection string? 
How do I configure things now? For example I remember doing this with the connectionString in a MVC5 app

```
 MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

How do I do it now?

Thanks!
Cheers!

PS

Also I have the following code in my App.config in the Repository.EF Project

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
 <configSections>

 <section name="entityFramework"
 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, 
 EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"  
 requirePermission="false" />
 <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit 
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
 <entityFramework>
 <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory,
 EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>

</entityFramework>
```

Comment: your connection string should be in the web.config of your web project

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the quick reply. However, the problem is , there is no web.config in this project. This project is just a class library where I have all my POCO's . So I have added EF to it. The idea is to keep this layer separate and use it just for data access.

Comment: You separate class library will be loaded in some application in order to work so it will use connection string from its 'host' application.

Comment: When you create a library and the library is referenced from another project, EF will read the config that is relative to start up project. otherwise you have an app.config with connection string inside or else should be on your datacontext ctor

Comment: I have added my app.config here. Please have a look and tell me if I can add my connectionString here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running the package manager console it will default to use the start-up project (unless you specify the -project param in the command or use the drop down in console manager). From there it will look for your connection strings in the config files of that project. If that is a web project this will be in the web.config.

If you have not added your own connection string to that project, EF will be able to use its own one derived from the project name and create an mdf file which it attaches on the fly during runtime.

If you want to add a connection string (you can do this is any of your config files - however by the sounds of it you want to add this to the app.config in your datalayer project) you can add this below your config sections:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyDatabase"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have changed the project using the dropdown list so all the Migration folders and stuff are in the correct project where I wanted them. How do I add my own connection string ?

Comment: you can specify a connection string name and project name from another project, but keep your migrations in your data tier if you want. eg. update-database -project "learningspike.web" -connectionstringname "GlassContract"

Comment: Can you please explain it to me in detail. Sorry for the trouble. I understand your concept . How do I do it?

Comment: ive extended my answer to include how to add a connection string to your app.config in your data layer project

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks so much for your effort . There is still a bit of a problem . I thought EF will create a new database in the folder I name in the connection string. But it still seems like ignoring that and creates its own.I have deleted and added everything back but still no luck. Maybe I need to learn more about EF and connection strings.